# Angular2 Spotify API - Error loading :(

Tags: angular, spotify

I'm currently trying to develop an Angular 2 Spotify web app and while looking on the internet I came across this: https://github.com/eduardolima93/angular2-spotify

However, I keep getting an error that I can't seem to quite figure out how to solve it. The error is:

```
Error loading http://localhost:3000/angular2-spotify as "angular2-spotify" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
```

Here is a direct link to my app.zip:
https://github.com/eduardolima93/angular2-spotify/files/253681/ang.zip

Just use "npm install". Hopefully someone can help me debug this.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please post the RELEVANT files here, specifically how you're mapping your files and what package loader you're using.

Comment: You can't expect anyone to download zip files from "unknown sources" to the local disk.

Comment: The Package.json file is in the zip you literally just have to run npm install.....

Comment: Or you could post the package.json file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

After having installed the module using NPM, you need to configure it into a `map` block in your SystemJS configuration:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      'angular2-spotify': 'node_modules/angular2-spotify/dist/angular2-spotify.js'
    },
    packages: {
      (...)
    }
  });
</scrip>
```